# Word for sphere of reality surrounding each individual?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the sphere reality that is being perceived by an individual?

One can consider that there are two parts to awareness, first one is the subject that is aware and secondly what the subject is aware of/perceives, the best description I can think of for that is “sphere of (realised) reality of each individual (cognisant being).”

So if the word *cognisant* describes the individual in the above model, what word would describe the thing that the individual is cognisant of?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on philosphySE. 

Answer (score 1):

**[Environment](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/environment)**: the aggregate of surrounding things, conditions, or influences; surroundings; milieu.

**[Surroundings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surroundings)**: The external circumstances, conditions, and objects that affect existence and development; the environment.

**[Milieu](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/milieu)**: surroundings, especially of a social or cultural nature.

Interestingly, synonyms for milieu are: background, **sphere**, setting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to fully understand the question, but imagine some of the following terms are relevant.
• *[space](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/space#Noun)*, “The physical and psychological area one needs within which to live or operate; personal freedom”
• *[aura](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aura#Noun)*, “An invisible force surrounding a living creature” and  “Distinctive atmosphere or quality associated with something”
• *[medium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medium#Noun)*, “The material or empty space through which signals, waves or forces pass”
• *[milieu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milieu#Noun)*, “A person's social setting or environment”